# call to php function on another page not working Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined

Tags: php, function, include, require

I am trying to call a function in another page and getting : Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined

Two pages are index.php and functions.php

Code Blocks:

Index.php

```
if($result) {
    // Make sure there are some files in there
    if($result == '') {
        echo '<h1>There are no files in the database</h1>';
    }
    else {

require './functions.php';
        // Print the top of a table
        echo '<table class="table-survey" style="margin-left: 50px; width: 1400px;">
                <th>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>CSSID</b></td>
                    <td><b>GROUP</b></td>
                    <td><b>Class</b></td>
                    <td><b>Gross Commission Amount</b></td>
                    <td><b>Name</b></td>
                    <td><b>Email Address</b></td>
                    <td><b>Email Received</b></td>
                    <td><b>Email Sent</b></td>
                    <td><b>Notes from December</b></td>
                    <td><b>Not Used For Business</td>
                </tr>
                </th>';
        // Print each file
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>{$row['cssid']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['grp']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['css_class']}</td>
                    <td>$" . number_format($row['gross_commission_amount'], 2) . "</td>
                    <td>{$row['FName']} {$row['LName']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['email_address']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['email_received']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['email_sent']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['additional_notes']}</td>";
if($delemail == $row) {
                echo "<td><form><input value={$row['email_address']} type='radio' name='selected_already' checked='checked'></input></form>/td>";
}
else{

echo "<td><form method='post' action='functions.php'><input value={$row['email_address']} type='radio' name='optradio' onchange='test(this.value);'></input></form></td>";

}
              echo "</tr>";
```

functions.php

```
function test(){

if (!$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'dummydata', 'dummydata')) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db('test_table', $link)) {
    echo 'Could not select database';
    exit;
}


if (isset($_POST['optradio'])) {

$sql = "update email_data set additional_notes_new = case when additional_notes_new is null then 'NOT USED FOR BUSINESS' else concat(additional_notes_new, 'NOT USED FOR BUSINESS') END WHERE email_address = '$delemail' and additional_notes_new NOT LIKE '%NOT USED FOR BUSINESS%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$link);



}
return false;

};
```

All of the POST and other data is working including the SQL statements before the pasted code. As soon as I click the radio button to call the function I get the error. Please excuse the code I am still learning.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Are you trying to include function.php in index.php?

Comment: Thank you Jay. I'll switch it out

Comment: I am trying to include functions.php so I can call the function test in it.

Comment: I don't see an `include()` directive anywhere in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
onchange='test(this.value);'
```

to

```
  onClick='$.post("somewhere.php",{posteddata:$(this).val()},function(){ })'
```

its will $_POST['posteddata'] to somewhere.php

Answer (score 0):

Your `test` function is php, if you're doing an `onchange` call it will try and find a function called `test` in Javascript. If you want to call the `test` function trough an onclick event without refreshing the page you're looking for something called `ajax` more info on `ajax` can be found here : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sorry, was meant to be the `onchange` function, it's in his last `echo` from `index.php`

Comment: Thank you Gerton, pretty sure that will be what I need. I am going to modify the calls this morning.